# How to reset nodejs stream?

Tags: node.js, stream, fs

How to reset nodejs stream?
How to read stream again in nodejs?
Thanks in advance!

```
var fs = require('fs');
var lineReader = require('line-reader');

// proxy.txt = only 3 lines

var readStream = fs.createReadStream('proxy.txt');
lineReader.open(readStream, function (err, reader) {
    for(var i=0; i<6; i++) {
        reader.nextLine(function(err, line) {
            if(err) {
                readStream.reset(); // ???
            } else {
                console.log(line);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: why not just put what you have in a function and call it?

Comment: Yes, there will be function called "getNextProxy()". I want to make it work even proxylist ends.

Comment: Now I close this stream and open new the same in this situation. But maybe there is better solution?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There are two ways of solving your problem, as someone commented before you could simply wrap all that in a function and instead of resetting - simply read the file again.

Ofc this won't work well with HTTP requests for example so the other way, provided that you do take a much bigger memory usage into account, you can simply accumulate your data.

What you'd need is to implement some sort of "rewindable stream" - this means that  you'd essentially need to implement a Transform stream that would keep a list of all the buffers and write them to a piped stream on a rewind method.

Take a look at the [node API for streams](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_implementing_a_duplex_stream) here, the methods should look somewhat like this.

```
class Rewindable extends Transform {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.accumulator = [];
  }

  _transform(buf, enc, cb) { 
    this.accumulator.push(buf);
    callback()
  }

  rewind() {
    var stream = new PassThrough();
    this.accumulator.forEach((chunk) => stream.write(chunk))
    return stream;
  }
```

And you would use this like this:

```
var readStream = fs.createReadStream('proxy.txt');
var rewindableStream = readStream.pipe(new Rewindable());

(...).on("whenerver-you-want-to-reset", () => {
    var rewound = rewindablesteram.rewind();
    /// and do whatever you like with your stream.
});
```

Actually I think I'll add this to my [`scramjet`](https://github.com/MichalCz/scramjet). :)

#### Edit

I released the logic below in [`rereadable-stream`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rereadable-stream) npm package. The upshot over the stream depicted here is that you can now control the buffer length and get rid of the read data.

At the same time you can keep a window of `count` items and tail a number of chunks backwards.

Comment: Wouldn't your stream package get all buffers in memory ? Wouldn't that defy the stream purpose ?

Comment: Well sadly yes, but I'd be happy to work on a spill to disk feature if I see enough interest. As to defying the stream purpose, then not necessarily - think about handling two requests for the same thing - one is served immediately, the other can catch up and use the same stream. It all depends on your use case.

Comment: I do not think that it is the way to go but sincronize yourself the reads/writes using a transform stream. This is solution is not better than getting the stream twice from the source because it is very constrained to size and size it is imo why streams are useful.

Comment: That depends on the effort it takes to get the stream. Imagine a simple HLS video chunk in live streaming - you'll have a lot of requests for the same data, 6-12 latest chunks of the video. You know the size and reading it from memory makes a lot of sense.

Comment: I think that is not a good example either. Imagine trying to rewind a LIVE chunk ? 
Also I would say if you only need 6 - 12 chunks that it is a very very specific edge case.

Comment: @iwaduarte that very very specific edge case is how all IPTV systems work. Also imagine a system that just keeps a number of elements of history - 1000 latest lines of log, a simple: `new Rereadable({length: 1000})` would work nicely and I don't think it's a very very specific case.

Comment: Besides to your point - it's up to you to choose the right method for your use case. I answered a very specific question and you seem to apply that to cases not described here. I don't see why you wouldn't just not use it if it doesn't fit your case.