# Get hash of ReadStream and output data of stream

Tags: node.js, node-streams

I have a ReadStream that I want to read multiple times. The readStream is created with fs.createReadStream.

First time I'm using it to get it's `md5` hash, I'm doing it with module `hasha`, function `fromStream`, and the second time I'm using it with `FormData` to upload a file to web hosting.

How can I use this one ReadStream to do both of these things?

```
readStream = fs.createReadStream("/tmp/test.txt");
hash = await hasha.fromStream(readStream, hashOptions);
readStream.on("data", (chunk) => console.log("data chunk", chunk)).on("end", () => console.log("finished"));
```

It's not loging the content to the console as it should, probably because in the `hasha.fromStream` it's `pipe`-ing the stream. If I don't execute `hasha.fromStream` it's working fine, the chunks are logged.

The module I'm using, called `hasha` is on github: https://github.com/sindresorhus/hasha/blob/master/index.js#L45

I don't want to save the data to buffer before getting hash, because I'll be using it with large files.

I have also made a runkit script showing my problem, you can play with it there:
https://runkit.com/5942fba4653ae70012196b77/5942fba4653ae70012196b78

Comment: Perhaps use something like this? https://github.com/karmadude/stream-n-way

Comment: thanks, but it's not what I'm looking for

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a standalone example on how to "fork" a stream so you can pipe it to two destinations:

```
const PassThrough = require('stream').PassThrough;

async function hashAndPost(stream) {
  let pass1 = new PassThrough();
  let pass2 = new PassThrough();

  stream.pipe(pass1);
  stream.pipe(pass2);

  // Destination #1
  pass1.on('data', chunk =>
    console.log('data chunk', chunk.toString())
  ).on('end', () =>
    console.log('finished')
  );

  // Destination #2
  let hash = await hasha.fromStream(pass2, { algorithm : 'md5' });
  console.log('hash', hash);
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You can either recreate the stream by re-reading the file, or you can rewind the stream, as explained here: [How to reset nodejs stream?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36980201/how-to-reset-nodejs-stream)

Comment: I don't like how it saves the buffers to array, what if the stream is possibly 10gb? About recreating - in the module I'm making on the input I'm taking only the stream, I don't know the file path or even if it is a file.

Comment: @xerq I actually published a package since that answer: [rereadable-stream](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rereadable-stream). It does still accumulate a stream portion in an array, but you can control it.

If you just need to push the stream in two directions - why not pipe twice?